# Adding a user to an existing database audit specification in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, auditing

I want to add a new user to an existing database audit specification but I am having the following error and I have tried all the things I know

INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR '='

ALTER DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [Log_File]
ADD (PRINCIPAL = 'Engineer1');
GO

Comment: The [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-audit-specification-transact-sql) is `ALTER DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION ... ADD (<action> ON <securable> BY <principal>)`, and `PRINCIPAL` is not a keyword. You cannot just "add a user", you need to specify what actions on what securables by that user you'd like to add. This may mean having to repeat all existing actions in the audit; if necessary these can be scripted out using `sys.database_audit_specification_details`.